# Mututal Information in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mutual-information

I expected sklearn's [mutual_info_classif](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html) to give a value of 1 for the mutual information of a series of values with itself but instead I'm seeing results ranging between about 1.0 and 1.5.  What am I doing wrong?

This [video on mutual information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9h1xkNELvY) (from 4:56 to 6:53) says that when one variable perfectly predicts another then the mutual information score should be log_2(2) = 1.  However I do not get that result:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
print("Confusion matrix:")
print(confusion_matrix(y,y))

print("Mutual information:")
result = mutual_info_classif(pd.DataFrame(y), y)
print(result)
```

which gives:

```
Confusion matrix:
[[5 0]
 [0 5]]
Mutual information:
[1.28730159]
```

When the two variables are independent, I do however see the expected value of zero:

```
x = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
y = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]

print("Confusion matrix:")
print(confusion_matrix(x,y))

print("Mutual information:")
result = mutual_info_classif(pd.DataFrame(x), y)
print(result)
```

which gives:

```
Confusion matrix:
[[5 5]
 [5 5]]
Mutual information:
[0]
```

Why am I not seeing a value of 1 for the first case?

Comment: In any case in the video he gets to say that when one variable perfectly predicts another the mutual information has to be log(2). Then he chooses a log basis for the problem, but this is not how sklearn implemented its modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sklearn has different objects dealing with mutual information score.

What you are looking for is the [`normalized_mutual_info_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score.html).

The `mutual_info_score` and the `mutual_info_classif` they both take into account (even if in a different way, the first as a denominator, the second as a numerator) the integration volume over the space of samples.

Your code becomes

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import normalized_mutual_info_score, mutual_info_score

y = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
print("Confusion matrix:")
print(confusion_matrix(y,y))

print("Mutual information:")
result = normalized_mutual_info_score(y, y)
result_not_normalised = mutual_info_score(y,y)
print('norm: ', result)
print('not-norm: ', result_not_normalised)
```

giving,

```py
Confusion matrix:
[[10  0]
 [ 0 10]]
Mutual information:
norm:  1.0
not-norm:  0.6920129648318737
```

Note also that $ln(2) \simeq 0.6931$.